# First layer failing due to delayed and dragged extrusion

Tags: creality-ender-3

I've had a handful of successful prints with my 3D printer, but at some point it just stopped being able to put down a first layer. It looks like the issue is that the extruder doesn't start putting down plastic right away, and when it moves to a new point, drags it along with it.

I've leveled the bed, added a BLTouch, upgraded the extruder feeder after the original cracked, cleaned the bed, cleaned the hot end, replaced the nozzle and tried different filament. Nothing seems to change it.

If I let it continue it inevitably fails completely by the second layer.

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11yFF3Acto4LtDJMBsdVsxr1PvmyMG2qR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you start the print with a skirt? What is your first layer thickness? What is your first layer speed? First layer temperature- bed, hotend? Do you use anything on the glass, glue, hairspray? Do you do a nozzle prime move before the start of the print? Do you pull goobers and ooze off the nozzle with tweezers before the print starts?

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out! My extruder calibration was way off (set to 93 but measured to 102). I'm thinking that after I replaced the extruder feeder it through things off.

Comment: I would not expect that little error in extrusion (10% overextrusion compared to setting) to cause first layer adhesion failure.  Usually that's due to either nozzle too high (= bed too low), or a worn/dirty build surface.  Slow start or no extrusion is probably your Bowden tube backed up from the nozzle -- lots of information around about that, going back to the introduction of the Ender 3 (and all of its clones).